# Store Procedures with Dapper.Contrib

Tags: dapper, dapper-contrib

I am newbie to Dapper and I Want to use Dapper.Contrib. Is there any method we can use store procedure with Dapper.Contrib methods.

e.g The method of Dapper.Contrib is `connection.GetAll<Invoice>().ToList();`. I want to call store procedure in this extension methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stored procedures, use `.Query<T>` extension.

```
var result = cnn.Query<Data>("spGetData", new {Id = 1}, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Here is a [Link](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs) to sql mapper extensions source code.

Comment: The problem is that "vanilla" Dapper ignores properties attributes like [Computed]... so being able to execute Stored Procedures with Dapper.Contrib would be quite useful in some circumstances.